Не переведена фраза о допустимых типах файлов при загрузке изображений в вопрос
Не переведена фраза Supported file types: jpeg, png, gif, or bmp (Max size 2 MiB):


Подкорректировал и утвердил перевод, дополнительно обновил/добавил ещё несколько релевантных.
Будет в новых сборках. Текущая 2024.5.22.9600

Хм, сборка уже 2024.5.23.9693, а надпись-то на английском...

@wchistow общая проблема с переводами ещё не решена. Поэтому сложно предсказать, когда переводы реально смогут попасть на сайт. Ответа о том, как должен работать весь процесс обновления переводов тоже пока никакого нет.

@wchistow подхватилось 2024.5.24.9787
